# How can you recover the source code from a pure JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

By Pure, I mean in the sense of the λ-calculus, i.e., a single-argument function containing nothing on its body other than single-argument functions and single argument function calls. By recovering the source code, I mean up to variable renaming. So, for example,

```
n2 = function(v0){return function(v1){return v0(v0(v1))}}
console.log(source(n2));
console.log(source(n2(n2)));
```

Should print:

```
function(v0){return function(v0){return v0(v0(v1))}}
function(v0){return function(v0){return v0(v0(v0(v0(v1))))}}
```

That is, the first line shows the original source of the function `n2`, and the second one shows the source of the function that is returned by the evaluation of `n2(n2)`.

I've managed to implement it as follows:

```
function source(f){
    var nextVarId = 0;
    return (function recur(f){
        if (typeof f === "function"){
            if (f.isVarFunc) return f(null);
            else {
                var varName = "v"+(nextVarId++);
                var varFunc = function rec(res){
                    var varFunc = function(arg){
                        return arg === null
                            ? "("+res.join(")(")+")"
                            : rec(res.concat(recur(arg)));
                    };
                    varFunc.isVarFunc = true;
                    return varFunc;
                };
                varFunc.isVarFunc = true;
                var body = f(varFunc([varName]));
                body     = body.isVarFunc ? body(null) : recur(body);
                return "(function("+varName+"){return "+body+"})";
            };
        } else return f;
    })(f);
};
```

The issue is that I'm using some rather ugly method of tagging functions by setting their names to a specific value, and that it won't work in functions that are applied more than once (such as `a(b)(b)`). Is there any better principled way to solve this problem?

Edit: I managed to design a version that seems to be correct in all cases, but it is still an ugly unreadable unprincipled mess.

Comment: That's not how closures work. A reference to the closed-over scope is created, the code remains unchanged.

Comment: You might rather want to implement your own lambda calculus interpreter in JS (it's not that complicated) than messing with JS functions and JS code.

Comment: The point of the code is to force the V8 engine to evaluate the JavaScript function to normal form, which means every closure collapses.

Comment: I have written several lambda calculus interpreters on JavaScript, actually, inclusive one asymptotically faster than V8 itself ([Optlam](http://github.com/maiavictor/optlam)), but you simply can't make interpreters run faster than native functions in many cases, so I specifically need what I asked.

Comment: Your problem is that `n2(n2)` does create a function that is a JS closure, not collapsed, and as such does not provide any access to its inside (closed-over variables, I mean, the code is not enough). You can of course write your own `apply(n2, [n2])` function that does create normal-form functions.

Comment: Fair, I'm thinking on that approach right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this is a considerably cleaned up version of the mess above.

```
// source :: PureFunction -> String
// Evaluates a pure JavaScript function to normal form and returns the 
// source code of the resulting function as a string.
function source(fn){
    var nextVarId = 0;
    return (function normalize(fn){
        // This is responsible for collecting the argument list of a bound
        // variable. For example, in `function(x){return x(a)(b)(c)}`, it
        // collects `a`, `b`, `c` as the arguments of `x`.  For that, it
        // creates a variadic argumented function that is applied to many
        // arguments, collecting them in a closure, until it is applied to
        // `null`. When it is, it returns the JS source string for the
        // application of the collected argument list.
        function application(argList){
            var app = function(arg){
                return arg === null
                    ? "("+argList.join(")(")+")"
                    : application(argList.concat(normalize(arg)));
            };
            app.isApplication = true;
            return app;
        };
        // If we try to normalize an application, we apply
        // it to `null` to stop the argument-collecting.
        if (fn.isApplication) 
            return fn(null);
        // Otherwise, it is a JavaScript function. We need to create an
        // application for its variable, and call the function on it.
        // We then normalize the resulting body and return the JS
        // source for the function.
        else {
            var varName = "v"+(nextVarId++);
            var body    = normalize(fn(application([varName])));
            return "(function("+varName+"){return "+body+"})";
        };
    })(fn);
};
```

It is still not perfect but looks much better nether less. It works as expected:

```
console.log(source(function(a){return function(b){return a(b)}}))
```

Outputs:

```
(function(v0){return (function(v1){return (v0)((v1))})})
```

I wonder how inefficient that is, though.

Comment: This code really should be an edit to the original question. FWIW, you _might_ get more of a response if you explain _why_ you want to do this stuff. (BTW, I came here via your SO Meta question).

Comment: @PM2Ring - If this answers the original question then why should it be an edit instead of an answer?

Comment: @BSMP: It's _ok_ as an answer, but IMHO it belongs in the question because it's more like a progress report on Viclib's efforts to resolve the problem, and it mentions that it doesn't totally solve the original problem, since Viclib still has questions relating to the efficiency of this approach. But I _certainly_ wouldn't down-vote it, or flag it for deletion!

Comment: I posted since, if the scope of this question would be as to not cover the efficiency aspect, then this is the actual answer. I messed up with the question, though.

Comment: I wanted this to force the evaluation of pure JavaScript functions, in order to avoid the thunk to grow indefinitely.